# What is the meaning of following line in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

What is use of line:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
```

in vbscript code.

Comment: What does Google says?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create a WMI object that provides you with the objects, methods and properties needed to be able to communicate with the different parts of the OS.

So, using your snippet, you could for example query the status of every service:

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService  = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colRunningServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Service")

For Each objService in colRunningServices    
  MsgBox objService.Name & " - " & objService.State
Next
```

You aren't limited to services, you can access registry settings, active process, etc. I use it often at work to help manage our Windows environment.

A few resources:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394585(v=vs.85).aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176998.aspx